# C++ - pass array by ref

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pass-by-reference

what if I want to pass an array by ref? An array is a pointer to its first element, and I want to pass the 'whole array' by ref. If I define

```
void someFunction(double& adouble){...}
```

then adouble is a ref to a double, not an array with doubles.

If I define

```
void anotherFunction(double* adouble){...}
```

then my argument is a pointer to a double or an array, but it is not passed by ref, right?

Thanks and regards

Comment: An array is not a pointer to its first element. An array is an array. A pointer is a pointer. And if you want to pass around arrays, you almost certainly want to use `std::vector` instead

Comment: One comment is not enough: **AN ARRAY IS NOT A POINTER**. Get that incorrect notion out of your head before it causes you any more trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a specific size:

```
void foo(double (&array)[100]);
```

For any size:

```
template <size_t N>
void foo(double (&array)[N]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
void foo(double *& bar)
```

Comment: This passes a pointer via reference, which is pretty much useless if you want an array.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use a struct as a wrapper to pass the array, this can make it more convenient in some cases. An example:

```
const int N = 100;

struct ArrayWrapper
{
  double adouble[N];
};

void foo(ArrayWrapper& wrapper)
{
  // ...
}
```